# SQLITE_BUSY Azure read-only issue with Node.js

Tags: node.js, azure, sqlite, express

I'm trying to get my React/Node/Express app deployed to Azure and everything is working so far except I cannot write to the sqlite3 database. Whenever a function attempts to write the logs show the following error:

```
SQLITE_BUSY: database is locked
```

I suspect that the .sqlite file is read-only, but have no idea how to change this. Any help greatly appreaciated!

Comment: Sqlite allows only one writer to the whole database at a time. Seems that you are doing multiple writes simultaneously. Or maybe you are using multiple connections at the same time. Anyway if you want to try to add write permissions use ```chmod +rwx```. I doubt thats the issue tho

Comment: sqlite db is only accessed through a single express instance so I don't think this is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the issue here was the default way that Azure/VS Code deploys is into a read-only wwwroot folder. In the end I abandoned sqlite and converted everything to Azure SQL DB and working flawlessly, but was a fair bit of work to transition.